# DebugView in Firebase not displaying my device. I'm using MBP M1. It gets recognized when i debug on my Windows

Tags: android, firebase, adb

Pretty much what the title says.

Whenever I try to debug an app using my Macbook Pro M1, even though adb is installed and running, I can't get Firebase to recognize my device (I need to see the events).

But when I debug on my Windows laptop, it works. What can be wrong here? Help!

Answer (score 0):

I simply used `adb -d shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app <my_app>` and problem solved.

The `-d` made the difference.